# prometheus relabel instance

Tags: prometheus, open-telemetry-collector

I currently have this metric:

```
os_processor_information_processor_time_percent{instance="3,9"} 0.026940740009384623
```

I would like to change the labeling to be:

```
os_processor_information_processor_time_percent{instance="3,9",nodegroup="3",core="9"}
```

Is this possible?

I was trying to do this on prometheus side. But if doable on opentelemetry collector side, that would be fine too. I couldn't get it going with the metricstransform or the new ottl.

Comment: Do you want this to be done on scraping stage or when querying data from Prometheus?

Comment: I was attempting scraping, but if it could be done within grafana I'd take that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to do this in the otelcollector, you can use the transform processor ([docs here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/transformprocessor)).

If you'd like to do this in prometheus's scrape config, you can do this by using a [`metric_relabel_configs`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) like so:

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - action: replace
    regex: "([0-9]+),[0-9]+"
    replacement: "${1}"
    separator: ";"
    source_labels:
    - instance
    target_label: nodegroup
  - action: replace
    regex: "[0-9]+,([0-9]+)"
    replacement: "${1}"
    separator: ";"
    source_labels:
    - instance
    target_label: core
```

Comment: I would like to mention, that `separator` is redundant here, since you have a single `source_label`. Also, `action` and `replacement` can be skipped too, since they contain default values.

Comment: will this apply to any metric with instance="x,y" or can it be confined to just os_processor_information_processor_time_percent

Comment: i read the otelcollector doc, but it wasn't clear to me how to do it.  the scrape config might be sufficient.  I'm testing it now.

Comment: @rismoney, it will be applied to all. To limit it only to `os_processor_information_processor_time_percent` you'll need to change following configs: `source_labels: [__name__, instance]`, `regex: "os_processor_information_processor_time_percent;[0-9]+,([0-9]+)"`

Answer (score 1):

You can add labels based on values of other labels within your query using function [`label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace).

It takes five parameters:

1. instant selector (for example `up{instance="localhost:8192"}`),
2. destination label: name of new label,
3. replacement string (for example "$1"),
4. source label: label whose value will be used to create new label,
5. regex pattern: regex matcher for value of source label.

In your case query will look like this:

```
label_replace(
 label_replace(
  os_processor_information_processor_time_percent{},
  "nodegroup", "$1",
  "instance", "(.+),.+"
 ),
 "core", "$1",
 "instance", ".+,(.+)"
)
```

Here we apply `label_replace` two times to add two labels.